# Turn http request into axios call

Tags: javascript

How do i convert the following http request into an axios call? The following call works correctly but i'm not familiar enough to convert it to an axios call.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/v1/storage/upload
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----my-form-data
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}

------my-form-data
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="protrait.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg

< C:/Users/johndoe/Documents/portrait.jpg
------my-form-data--
```

I was trying to do where 'file' is the file object from a file input field.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append({
    name: "file",
    filename: file.name,
});
const res = await api({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/v1/storage/upload",
    data: formData,
});
```

I get the following error...

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? `append` takes two arguments, and you are passing it one. Look at [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) to see how to call it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` takes as input `name` and `value`, bur you are giving it in input only a dictionary with two couples name/value.

You could try the following code:

```js
formData.append("name", "file");
formData.append("filename", file.name);
```